# Set override backend path to empty string in App G/w Ingress Controller

Tags: azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

We are using Azure App G/w Ingress Controller to expose services hosted within AKS.
E.g.
Service named **abc** is hosted in AKS as below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    project: abc
    app: abc
    env: dev
  name:  abc
  namespace: abc
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    # This is the external port of the cluster
    port: 8443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    project: abc
    app:  abc
    env: dev
  type: ClusterIP
```

**Ingress Configuration**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-abc
  namespace: abc
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: "/"
rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: abc
          servicePort: 9000
        path: /abc*
```

**Problem Statement**

Front-end will send request to the backend like: *https://app-gw-ip/**abc/operation***.

App G/w applies appropriate routing rule and converts the request_uri to "//operation". "**abc**" in the **URL  path** is **overwritten by "/"** because of the backend-path-prefix annotation. Whereas we want the request_uri as "**/operation**"

**Is there a way to set backend-path-prefix to empty string ?**

**I want to replace "abc/" in the URL path with "/".** Currently it replaces **"abc"** with **"/"**.

If I do not use the backend-path-prefix, then backend uri path will be "abc/operation". This will return 404 because abc service will not have any endpoint named abc/operation.

Comment: Did you try rewrite rules for the path based rules?

Answer (score 0):

Just use path as `path: /abc/*`

```
   apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: ingress-abc
      namespace: abc
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
        appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: "/"
    rules:
      - http:
          paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: abc
              servicePort: 9000
            path: /abc/*
```

Comment: then my css wont load...